# In SQL Server, locate backup file UI does not support location browsing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Maybe many of you have wasted a lot of time on this when backup or restore a database using SQL Server 2008

Every time it comes back to the default location, and the form doesn't have a browse button, moreover, when pasting a URL the tree doesn't refresh, So it forcing you to walk though the Tree to find the location or to prepare your URL and file name manually and then paste it.

My question, Is there any technical reason that makes it very hard to have this simple functionality in such important form.

Comment: Seems like something better raised on [Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback)

Comment: @MartinSmith, I didn't understand what you mean, do you asking me to submit a feedback ticket?

Comment: You could buy a tool that has a normal GUI, like RedGate Backup, or you could do restores using T/SQL's RESTORE command.  Having said that, I don't think this is a constructive question.

Comment: @ALA - Yes If you find the behaviour annoying then you are much better off submitting feedback about it. If people agree they will upvote it and it might get implemented in a future version.

Comment: I believe that there is a technical reason behind that limitation , that's why i asked this question.

Comment: I doubt it. Just one of many aspects of SSMS that are less than user friendly. It would need to remember your preference for each instance rather than just sticking it in a global registry key and it can only access folders that the SQL Server service account has permissions on but neither of these explain why the dialogue doesn't allow you to paste a path in to open up the treeview at that path.

Comment: @MartinSmith, Thanks for your comment, I have submitted a feedback about it [HERE](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/773894/in-sql-server-ms-locate-backup-file-ui-does-not-support-location-browsing) , please support to improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have submitted a feedback ticket about it [Here](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/773894/in-sql-server-ms-locate-backup-file-ui-does-not-support-location-browsing), please vote up if you think that a browse functionality should be there.